# Spring Data Rest ResourceProcessor not applied on Projections

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am using a ResourceProcessor to add additional links to my resource object when listed in a collection or fetched individually. However, when I apply a projection (or an excerpt project) to my repository, the ResourceProcessor does not get run and thus my links for that resource do not get created. Is there a means to allow my custom resource links to be added to a resource regardless of how the resource content is projected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue is describing your case:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-713

Currently, spring-data-rest does not offer functionality to solve your problem.

We are using a little workaround that still needs a separate `ResourceProcessor` for each projection but we do not need to duplicate the link logic:

We have a base class that is able to get the underlying Entity for a Projection and invokes the Entity's `ResourceProcessor` and applies the links to the Projection. 
`Entity` is a common interface for all our JPA entities - but I think you could also use `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable` or `org.springframework.hateoas.Identifiable`.

```
/**
 * Projections need their own resource processors in spring-data-rest.
 * To avoid code duplication the ProjectionResourceProcessor delegates the link creation to
 * the resource processor of the underlying entity.
 * @param <E> entity type the projection is associated with
 * @param <T> the resource type that this ResourceProcessor is for
 */
public class ProjectionResourceProcessor<E extends Entity, T> implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<T>> {

    private final ResourceProcessor<Resource<E>> entityResourceProcessor;

    public ProjectionResourceProcessor(ResourceProcessor<Resource<E>> entityResourceProcessor) {
        this.entityResourceProcessor = entityResourceProcessor;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Resource<T> process(Resource<T> resource) {
        if (resource.getContent() instanceof TargetAware) {
            TargetAware targetAware = (TargetAware) resource.getContent();
            if (targetAware != null
                    && targetAware.getTarget() != null
                    && targetAware.getTarget() instanceof Entity) {
                E target = (E) targetAware.getTarget();
                resource.add(entityResourceProcessor.process(new Resource<>(target)).getLinks());
            }
        }
        return resource;
    }

}
```

An implementation of such a resource processor would look like this:

```
@Component
public class MyProjectionResourceProcessor extends ProjectionResourceProcessor<MyEntity, MyProjection> {

    @Autowired
    public MyProjectionResourceProcessor(EntityResourceProcessor resourceProcessor) {
        super(resourceProcessor);
    }
}
```

The implementation itself just passes the ResourceProcessor that can handle the entity class and passes it to our `ProjectionResourceProcessor`. It does not contain any link creation logic.

Comment: thank you for your response. reading the ticket, it seems like there is some things that need to be worked out on the SD Rest side in regards to this issue. i've been able to move away from this for the time being but will keep an eye on the issue when and if i get back to using projections.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution:

```
@Component
public class ProjectionProcessor implements RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<TargetAware>> {

    private final RepresentationModelProcessorInvoker processorInvoker;

    public ProjectionProcessor(@Lazy RepresentationModelProcessorInvoker processorInvoker) {
        this.processorInvoker = processorInvoker;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityModel<TargetAware> process(EntityModel<TargetAware> entityModel) {
        TargetAware content = entityModel.getContent();
        if (content != null) {
            entityModel.add(processorInvoker.invokeProcessorsFor(EntityModel.of(content.getTarget())).getLinks());
        }
        return entityModel;
    }

}
```

It gets links for original entities and adds them to corrseponding projections.